# Select Statements in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to pull up one specific line from a database that I just typed information into.  This is the SELECT Statement that I typed in:

```
SELECT John 
FROM FoodLog
```

It comes up with the following error statement:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'John'.

However if I type the following SELECT Statement, it pulls up all of the information that I typed into the database:

```
SELECT Person
FROM FoodLog
```

I can't figure out how to pull up just one particular line of information from the database.

Comment: Please take a SQL tutorial before asking questions about SQL here. This is so very basic.

Comment: Try SAMS - teach yourself sql in 10 minutes. Not the best book, but its better than knowing nothing.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM FoodLog
WHERE Person = 'John'
```